# Best practise in hibernate update: selecting and setting or transaction?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, transactions

For this entity:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "user",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username"})}
)
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    @Column(name = "refresh_token")
    private String refreshToken;
}
```

Having Jpa repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);

    User findByRefreshToken(String token);

    @Modifying
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741102/how-to-beautifully-update-a-jpa-entity-in-spring-data
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.refreshToken = :refreshToken WHERE u.username = :username")
    void setRefreshToken(@Param("username") String username, @Param("refreshToken") String refreshToken);
}
```

and the service:

```
...
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void setRefreshToken(String username, String refreshToken) {
        userRepository.setRefreshToken(username, refreshToken);
    }
...
```

In controller, I have 2 option how to set refreshToken:

```
...
   User user = userService.getUserByUsername(userDtoin.username);
            String refreshToken = jwtService.generateToken(
                    REFRESH_TOKEN_DURATION_SECONDS * 1000,
                    Collections.singletonMap("username", user.getUsername())
            );
            userService.setRefreshToken(user.getUsername(), refreshToken);
...
```

I have decided to use the transaction. But I could do

```
...
User user = userService.getUserByUsername(userDtoin.username);
            String refreshToken = jwtService.generateToken(
                    REFRESH_TOKEN_DURATION_SECONDS * 1000,
                    Collections.singletonMap("username", user.getUsername())
            );
//            userService.setRefreshToken(user.getUsername(), refreshToken);
            user.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
            userService.saveUser(user);
...
```

What is better approach? Creating transaction at service level, or selecting an entity and the settings its value in java and saving it back? It will have 2 queries no matter the option (either select and update, or select and insert). But what is best practise for partial update in hibernate?